# Import root directory using babel-plugin-import is not working with Create-React-App

Tags: javascript, webpack, config, babeljs

My `.babelrc` config is not working. I keep getting this error message.
`Module not found: Can't resolve '@project/customTable' in...`

I want to shorten importing paths.

Can someone help me fix this?

Current code: `import customTable from "../../../customTable";`

Goal: `import customTable from "@project/customTable";`

Below is my `.babelrc` file:

```
{
  "plugins": [
    ["babel-plugin-root-import", {
      "rootPathSuffix": "src",
      "rootPathPrefix": "@project"
    }]
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> Use **Webpack** [alias](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/#resolvealias)

I'm not sure why your code ain't working. Everything seems to be fine. But, an alternative way would be to do this using Webpack aliases, like so:

```
modeule.exports = {
  entry: [
   require.resolve('./polyfills'),
   require.resolve('react-dev-utils/webpackHotDevClient'),
   paths.appIndexJs
  ],
  resolve: {
    alias: {
     '@project': path.join(__dirname, '../src') // <--- Here
    }
  }
}
```

**Q:** **But, I used `create-react-app`. I can't find webpack config files in my project directory? :(**

**A:** Run `npm run eject` and you'll get all the webpack configurations in a **config** folder of your project directory. :)

**Note:** Don't forget to restart your application after making all these changes to reflect.

Comment: Thank you for your solution. My primary goal is to make my configuration work if possible but I will definitely try this one.

Comment: @KenRyanLabso Sure, lemme know if my solution worked for you. :)

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you are using react-script in your project. You have to know you cant change the Babel config directly. you can use

```
npm run eject
```

but it's not a recommended way because by ejecting you'll lose some features like TypeScript, Sass, CSS Modules, and more.

by the way, you can use customize-cra and react-app-rewired npm packages. first, install them:

```
npm install customize-cra react-app-rewired --dev
//or
yarn add customize-cra react-app-rewired --dev
```

and create a config-overrides.js file in the same level where your package.json has placed.

and put the below config in it:

```
const { override, addBabelPlugins } = require("customize-cra");

module.exports = override(
  addBabelPlugins([
    "babel-plugin-root-import",
    { rootPathSuffix: "./src", rootPathPrefix: "@/" },
  ])
);
```

last but not least you have to change all react-script to react-app-rewired in your package.json file like:

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-app-rewired start",
    "build": "react-app-rewired build",
    "test": "react-app-rewired test",
    "eject": "react-app-rewired eject"
  },
```